# Google Drive comments API showing unresolved comments when there are none

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a Google Doc that I am testing the Comments API with. I've created, then deleted or resolved many comments. It currently shows no comments in the UI. However, when I search [Comments.Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/get) API on a specific Comment ID for the file, I am returned one that is both unresolved and not deleted. See API response below:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#comment",
 "commentId": "commentID",
 "createdDate": "2020-10-21T12:29:27.941Z",
 "modifiedDate": "2020-10-21T12:29:27.941Z",
 "author": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "My Name",
  "picture": {
   "url": "My Picture"
  },
  "isAuthenticatedUser": true
 },
 "htmlContent": "Comment",
 "content": "Comment",
 "deleted": false,
 "status": "open",
 "context": {
  "type": "text/html",
  "value": "some text in my file"
 },
 "anchor": "kix.bj5cxfssg70z",
 "fileId": "FileID",
 "fileTitle": "My File",
 "replies": []
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening. It's not a propagation issue (I hope) because I made all these changes to doc over an hour ago and still this is what I receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This can happen if you create a comment via API, especially if you do it for a file that does not support [programmatic anchoring](https://issuetracker.google.com/68244699)

So the comment is somewhere, you can see that it was created if you browse the Drive Activity (both prgramamtically and form the UI), but you cannot see the comment itself because it was wrongly anchored somewhere outside of the visible range of the document.

I assume it is related to [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/146053105). Comment on it to see if it gets reopened, or "star" the feature request to increase visibility.

Comment: Interesting, makes sense, but in my case this was a comment that I had made myself on the document (my use of Comments API is read-only). But to your point I'm wondering if the comment just lost its anchor in the document somehow

Comment: That's possible - apprently it is not unheard that comments just disappear: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6125696?hl=en You can still see them by clicking on the "Open comment history button".